# ASP Core Concurrent Requests Blocking at CORS Preflight

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors

I have a script that makes multiple POSTs to an endpoint containing JSON. At the moment, the script may make 100+ POSTs at the same time from localhost. The method for that route doesn't get invoked until all POSTs have been requested; until then, only HTTP OPTIONS (CORS preflight) is sent as the response. Once the script has stopped making POST requests, only then does the server start invoking the route method.

Of course, having the script make 100+ POST requests at the same time will be changed, but I'm concerned with how this will affect production use with many users.

In my debugging, I found that none of my filters/code are ran until all POST requests in that batch have been made.

I'm at a loss as to how to address this. CPU and memory aren't even close to reaching their limits, changing filter order has no effect, and optimizing the route method has had no effect since it isn't called until all requests have been made.

I'm testing this on a dev machine with Visual Studio on IIS Express 10. I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.0.

App configuration:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
            .AddMvc()
            .AddJsonOptions(opt =>
            {
                opt.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
            })
            .AddMvcOptions(opt =>
            {
                opt.Filters.Add(new IPLoggingInterceptionAttribute());
            });

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllOrigins", builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyHeader();
                builder.AllowAnyMethod();
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
            });
        });

        services
            .AddScoped<RequireAuthAttribute>();

        String connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("Vault");
        services.AddDbContext<VaultContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(connectionString));
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseCors("AllOrigins");

        app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.All,
            RequireHeaderSymmetry = false
        });

        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Route response method, in case it's relevant:

```
    [HttpPost("{villageId}/army/current")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostCurrentArmy(long villageId, [FromBody]JSON.ArmySet currentArmySetJson)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return ValidationProblem(ModelState);

        //  [Note that 'CurrentWorldId' is a blocking property on first read]
        //  Get or make CurrentVillage
        Scaffold.CurrentVillage currentVillage =
            await context.CurrentVillage
                .FromWorld(CurrentWorldId)
                .Where(v => v.VillageId == villageId)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        currentVillage = currentVillage ?? (await context.AddAsync(new Scaffold.CurrentVillage())).Entity;
        currentVillage.WorldId = CurrentWorldId;

        if (currentVillage.PlayerId == null)
        {
            var modelVillage = await (
                    from village in context.Village.FromWorld(CurrentWorldId)
                    where village.VillageId == villageId
                    select village
                ).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            if (modelVillage != null)
            {
                currentVillage.VillageId = modelVillage.VillageId;
                currentVillage.PlayerId = modelVillage.PlayerId;
                currentVillage.Points = modelVillage.Points;
                currentVillage.VillageName = modelVillage.VillageName;
                currentVillage.X = modelVillage.X.Value;
                currentVillage.Y = modelVillage.Y.Value;
            }
        }

        if (!Configuration.Security.AllowUploadArmyForNonOwner
                && currentVillage.PlayerId != CurrentUser.PlayerId)
        {
            await context.InvalidDataRecord.AddAsync(MakeInvalidDataRecord(
                JsonConvert.SerializeObject(currentArmySetJson),
                $"Attempted to upload current army to village {villageId} but that village is not owned by the requestor"
            ));
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Unauthorized();
        }

        var fullArmy = currentArmySetJson.Stationed + currentArmySetJson.Traveling + currentArmySetJson.Supporting;
        currentVillage.ArmyOwned     = ArmyConvert.JsonToArmy(fullArmy, currentVillage.ArmyOwned, context);
        currentVillage.ArmyStationed = ArmyConvert.JsonToArmy(currentArmySetJson.Stationed, currentVillage.ArmyStationed, context);
        currentVillage.ArmyTraveling = ArmyConvert.JsonToArmy(currentArmySetJson.Traveling, currentVillage.ArmyTraveling, context);


        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Ok();
    }
```

Comment: You certain its not the java script/browser which blocks? Also be aware, IIS Express isn't a real server, its for development

Comment: This should not be blocked by `Core App`. Share us the `script` which sent the `100+` requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Tseng was correct - the issue was the browser, which appeared to be holding the POST requests until the script was finished, but was not holding OPTIONS requests.

Answer (score 0):

As @Tseng pointed out try it on an IIS server (non dev). Before you go on to do that here are few things you should be able to go through quickly to rule out that your app isn't the cause for concern.

1. Are you 100% sure requests aren't hitting your netcore app? Can you
   check IIS logs and correlate timestamp? better yet have [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler)
   installed before you try again to make sure the requests are
   actually hitting your app right away and not queuing up for a one
   big blast?
2. Try a different browser as well. With all the optimizations browsers
       do these days with client side code there my be some quirks or the
       way you're making the request causing it to behave in a way you've
       described above (queuing up request to execute at once).

If the above two aren't the case and you can confirm all the request are hitting app right away then I'd suspect some type of blocking and or resource locking which is preventing all the requests to queue up.

Let us know what you find out. Good luck.